# Byte values in multi-byte UTF-8 characters

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I'm reading about [UTF-8 character encoding](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr17/#CharacterEncodingForm) but struggling to understand it.  I know that ASCII characters (that is, byte values `0x00` to `0x7F`) are represented in UTF-8 as a single byte.  The question I'm trying to answer is, **in the case of multi-byte UTF-8 characters, are the second and subsequent bytes always `0x80` to `0xFF`, or can they be any value?**

Comment: Take a look at the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/utf-8/info), and the RFC referenced there. Also, the wikipedia article isn't that bad. And a design-goal was making all start-bytes distinct from possible continuation-bytes.

Comment: @Deduplicator I just saw the relevant section of the wiki page and it clicked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a given Unicode codepoint value is U+0000 - U+007F, it fits in a single byte in UTF-8.  The byte's high bit is set to `0`, and the remaining 7 bits hold the bits of the codepoint value.

When a given Unicode codepoint value is U+0080 or higher, it requires 2-4 bytes in UTF-8, depending on the codepoint value (2 for U+0080 - U+07FF, 3 for U+0800 - U+FFFF, and 4 for U+10000 - U+1FFFFF).  The first byte's high bits are set to either `110`, `1110`, or `11110` to indicate how many bytes are in the full sequence (2-4, respectively).  The high bits of the subsequent byte(s) are set to `10`.  The rest of the bits of all of the bytes contain the bits of the codepoint value, spread out through the bytes as needed.

```
 Bits of       First       Last      Bytes in
code point  code point  code point   sequence   Byte 1    Byte 2    Byte 3    Byte 4
    7         U+0000      U+007F        1      0xxxxxxx 
    11        U+0080      U+07FF        2      110xxxxx  10xxxxxx 
    16        U+0800      U+FFFF        3      1110xxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx 
    21        U+10000     U+1FFFFF      4      11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx
```

Read the [description on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for more details.  It provides the above table, as well as a few examples.  Also read [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629), which is an official UTF-8 spec.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-byte representation of a character in UTF-8, *all* bytes are in the range 0x80 to 0xFF, i.e. they have the most significant bit set. This means that bytes 0x00 to 0x7F are used *only* as single-byte representations of ASCII characters (called Basic Latin in Unicode).